# Entity Framework Query Help

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity

Ok so I am just trying to learn some of this fun stuff now, and was wondering if I could get some feedback?

Tables
Categories
Postings
Postings_Categories(Join Table)

I need to figure out how to recurse through all of the categories and get the number of postings in each category. As well, if it can all be done with one query, I need to list the subcategories of each parent category.

Categories table has CategoryID, CategoryName, CategoryDescription, ParentCategoryID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nice if you wrote approach you used (DB first/Code First/POCOs). If DB first then easy:

```
context.Categories.Include('Subcategories').ToList();//list of categories and their subcategories

context.Categories.Select(c => new { Category = c, Postings = c.Postings.Count() }).ToList();//categories and number of postings
```

Of course your database needs to be set correctly, you have to create foreign keys, association table should have only ids of both tables. If database is not declared correctly, creating these queries could be problematic.

Comment: I do have Navigation Properties, rather than ("Subcategories") it would be "Postings_Categories"

Comment: How does Postings_Categories table look like?

Comment: PostingsCategoryID int IDENTTITY, PostingID, CategoryID

Comment: I need to get a result like this: CategoryName: Fruit, Apples, Grapes, Oranges (number:Postings)

Comment: @Anoddperson Iam: Remove PostingsCategoryID and then recreate edmx. This field is not necessary and ruins diagram.

Comment: SELECT Categories.CategoryName, COUNT(Postings.PostingID) AS NumPostings FROM Postings INNER JOIN Postings_Categories ON Postings.PostingID = Postings_Categories.PostingID RIGHT OUTER JOIN Categories ON Postings_Categories.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID GROUP BY Categories.CategoryName (How is this done using link to entities or entity SQL, I prefer entity SQL

Comment: This is done like I wrote, but only if you create your database and edmx model properly.